# Android Studio Convert Java To Kotlin 2 errors

Tags: android, kotlin

After Convert Java File to Kotlin File, gives me two errors in same line: In code below show variables and  function with error

```
     lateinit var ncArr: Array<ImageButton>
     lateinit var xBitmap: Bitmap
     lateinit var oBitmap: Bitmap
     lateinit var intArr: IntArray
     lateinit var btnStartGame: Button
     lateinit var btnMenu: Button
     var stop: Boolean = false
     var gameMode: Int = 0
     var umove: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onStart()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)

    ncArr = arrayOfNulls(9)

    ncArr[0] = findViewById(R.id.nc0) as ImageButton
    ncArr[1] = findViewById(R.id.nc1) as ImageButton
    ncArr[2] = findViewById(R.id.nc2) as ImageButton
    ncArr[3] = findViewById(R.id.nc3) as ImageButton
    ncArr[4] = findViewById(R.id.nc4) as ImageButton
    ncArr[5] = findViewById(R.id.nc5) as ImageButton
    ncArr[6] = findViewById(R.id.nc6) as ImageButton
    ncArr[7] = findViewById(R.id.nc7) as ImageButton
    ncArr[8] = findViewById(R.id.nc8) as ImageButton

    ncArr[0].setOnClickListener(this)
    ncArr[1].setOnClickListener(this)
    ncArr[2].setOnClickListener(this)
    ncArr[3].setOnClickListener(this)
    ncArr[4].setOnClickListener(this)
    ncArr[5].setOnClickListener(this)
    ncArr[6].setOnClickListener(this)
    ncArr[7].setOnClickListener(this)
    ncArr[8].setOnClickListener(this)

    xBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.x)
    oBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.o)

    intArr = IntArray(9)

    for (i in 0..8) {
        intArr[i] = 0
    }

    btnMenu = findViewById(R.id.btnMenu) as Button
    btnStartGame = findViewById(R.id.btnStartGame) as Button
    btnMenu.setOnClickListener(this)
    btnStartGame.setOnClickListener(this)

    stop = false

    gameMode = intent.getIntExtra("game_mode", 1)
    umove = 1
}
```

in line `ncArr = arrayOfNulls(9)`
There are errors:
[image]

I trying to fix this problem but i don't have more ideas...

Any sollution?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ncArr = arrayOfNulls(9)
```

The type of `ncArr` will be `Array<ImageButton?>`

```
ncArr[0] = findViewById(R.id.nc0) as ImageButton
```

You are using unsafe cast operator `as`, because the cast operator throws an exception if the cast is not possible. Thus, we call it unsafe. What happens if

```
findViewById(R.id.nc0) as ImageButton
```

return `null`, then `null` cannot assign to `ImageButton`, it will throw an exception and make your app crash.

To avoid the above error you can use

```
ncArr[0] = findViewById(R.id.nc0) as ImageButton?
```

or using safe cast operator `as?`

```
ncArr[0] = findViewById(R.id.nc0) as? ImageButton
```

Remember apply for `ncArr[0]` to `ncArr[8]`.

**Update**: Based on your request, you can use this solution:

```
lateinit var ncArr: Array<ImageButton>
    lateinit var xBitmap: Bitmap
    lateinit var oBitmap: Bitmap
    lateinit var intArr: IntArray
    lateinit var btnStartGame: Button
    lateinit var btnMenu: Button
    var stop: Boolean = false
    var gameMode: Int = 0
    var umove: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onStart()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)

        ncArr = arrayOf(
                findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.nc0).apply{setOnClickListener(this@GameActivity)},
                findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.nc1).apply{setOnClickListener(this@GameActivity)},
                findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.nc2).apply{setOnClickListener(this@GameActivity)},
                findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.nc3).apply{setOnClickListener(this@GameActivity)},
                findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.nc4).apply{setOnClickListener(this@GameActivity)},
                findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.nc5).apply{setOnClickListener(this@GameActivity)},
                findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.nc6).apply{setOnClickListener(this@GameActivity)},
                findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.nc7).apply{setOnClickListener(this@GameActivity)},
                findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.nc8).apply{setOnClickListener(this@GameActivity)}

        )

        xBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.x)
        oBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.o)

        // Your code here
        ...
}
```

Comment: is correct this way: `ncArr[0] = findViewById<ImageButton?>(R.id.nc0)`

Comment: I see your problem, change `lateinit var ncArr: Array<ImageButton>` to `lateinit var ncArr: Array<ImageButton?>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179673/discussion-between-son-truong-and-kalco-frkata).

Answer (score 0):

You trying to put Nullable array into NonNull. You may declare `intArr` as `Array<ImageButton?>` and everything will work.